# Replace ! with an empty character in Java

Tags: java, string

With the given input `test!! test!!! test !!!` the program below should return `test! test! test !` by removing all but one of '!' or '?' in a row.

However the program outputs it like this: `test!  test!   test ! !`

How would I remove the extra '!' or '?' characters?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);

for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++)
{   
    // Does string contain '?' or '!'
    if (input.charAt(i) == '?' || input.charAt(i) == '!') {
        // TODO: Remove extra characters
    }
    else
    {
         sb.setCharAt(i, input[i]);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I searched your question title on google verbatim and found multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. There is no such thing as an empty character.   So `sb.setCharAt(i, empty);` is *actually* replacing the character at position `i` with a NON-EMPTY character.  It looks like its is a space character; i.e. Unicode / ASCII `SP`.
2. You can use `deleteCharAt(1)` to remove a character at position `i` of a `StringBuilder`.  But beware that removing the character at position `i` causes the characters at `i + 1`, `i + 2` and so on to *change position*.  You need to take account of that in your code.